# UGC- published to website. Unable to save updates by visitor

Tags: 2011, ugc

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2. I have implemented UGC to show only moderated comments on the website. However once a comment is published to website, I am unable to edit my comment and save it from website. In the default UGC dreamweaver template design provided, there is a save and remove button on a submitted comment. I have a comment with the status, published to website. When I edit and submit this comment, it doesn't get submitted. 
Is this save button not supposed to be there for "published to website" comments ?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 2):

The problem was from my end. I have a class UGCSpamFilter (implements SpamFilter) that couldn't find email address or username when resubmitting an existing comment. This class should have thrown SpamFilterException but I couldn't find the exception anywhere.